# La raíz cúbica de -1 en Python no aparece como debería

Tags: python, matemáticas

Como sabrán, en Python las potencias se escriben como "x**y"; esto significa "x elevado a y". En matemática, si elevo un número a "1/2" es como sacarle la raíz cuadrada si lo elevo a "1/3" es la raíz cúbica; y así sucesivamente.

El caso es que cuando pruebo el programa y pido la raíz cúbica de "-1" me aparece la forma compleja, no la forma real. La raíz cúbica de "-1" es en efecto "-1", pero Python me lanza un número complejo que (si bien es correcto) en mi programa no me funciona.

¿Hay alguna forma de exigirle a Python que me retorne los datos como números reales y no complejos? Gracias. Este es el fragmento de código con el que tengo problema:

```
#Cuando 'p = 0' y 'q = 1', el valor de 'v'  debería ser '-1'
v = ((((-1 * q) / 2) - (((q ** 2) / 4) + ((p ** 3) / 27)) ** (1/2)) ** (1/3))
```

Answer (score 3):

En realidad, `-1` tiene 3 raices cúbicas en el plano complejo:

- e^((i π)/3) = 1/2 (1 + i sqrt(3)) ≈ 0.5 + 0.8660 i (*raiz primaria*)
- e^(i π) = -1 (*raiz real*)
- e^(-(i π)/3) = 1/2 (1 - i sqrt(3)) ≈ 0.5 -0.8660 i

Su representación:

[image: Representación raíz cúbica de -1]

Las tres soluciones son válidas. Si tienes que quedarte con una sería con la *raiz primaria* que se define para números complejos como la raiz cuya parte real sea mayor y, en caso de no ser única, la que tenga la parte imaginaria positiva. En este caso: `0.5 + 0.8660 i`, que es lo que hace python muy correctamente.

Aún siendo correcto, lo que esperas es la *raiz real*. Para conseguirlo, hay que usar siempre *radicandos positivos*, con lo que siempre se obtendrían soluciones reales como raices primarias. Se puede codificar como en la respuesta de @DannyTalent, o de modo más compacto de esta forma:

```py
import math

def cbrt(x):
    return math.copysign(abs(x)**(1/3),x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacer que *funcione* sería hacer una función para raíces cúbicas. Si el número es negativo, simplemente se le pone un símbolo negativo al valor absoluto del número al cubo (se le multiplica por -1):

```
def cube_root(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x ** (1./3)
    elif x < 0:
        return -abs(x) ** (1./3)
    else:
        return 0
```

Así, realizas tu operación

```
v = cube_root(((-1 * q) / 2) - (((q ** 2) / 4) + ((p ** 3) / 27)) ** (1/2))
```

Y te devuelve

```
-1.0
```